# Connect to Kusto using older java version

Tags: java, azure, java-8, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to connect to kusto from my repo and its using java 8. The prerequisite on the documentation is java 11 or older: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-java

What are the methods to connect to kusto if I am using Java 8?

```
ConnectionStringBuilder csb = ConnectionStringBuilder.createWithAadApplicationCredentials(clusterPath, appId, appKey, authorityId);
Client kustoClient = ClientFactory.createClient(csb);
```

Comment: Use an older version that supports JDK 8.

Answer (score 1):

The Java 11 requirement was introduced in version 4.0.0, please use any version prior to that.
example:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.kusto</groupId>
            <artifactId>kusto-ingest</artifactId>
            <version>(,4.0.0)</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [MSdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/get-started/app-set-up?tabs=java#prerequisites),

- you need Java 11 or later versions to connect to kusto using Java.
- And also, you must use Maven 3.6.3 or later versions.

*I tried to reproduce with Java 8 but got the below error:*

[image]

***Code Snippet:***

I tried with Java 11 and could get the expected results:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try {
      String clusterURI = "https://pravucluster.eastus.kusto.windows.net";
      ConnectionStringBuilder stringbuilder = ConnectionStringBuilder.createWithUserPrompt(clusterURI);

      try (Client kusto_client = ClientFactory.createClient(stringbuilder)) {
        String database = "sampledb";
        String query = "print dbcolumn='Hello Pravallika!'";
        KustoOperationResult kustoresponse = kusto_client.execute(database, query);

        KustoResultSetTable kustoresults = kustoresponse.getPrimaryResults();
        kustoresults.next();
        System.out.println(kustoresults.getString("dbcolumn"));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.kusto</groupId>
    <artifactId>kusto-data</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.kusto</groupId>
    <artifactId>kusto-ingest</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

***Authentication:***

[image]

[image]

***Response:***

[image]